# How are differential equations and stochastic differential equations different?

Tags: random-variable, stochastic-processes, pymc, differential-equations, diffusion

In the simplest terms, how are differential equations and stochastic differential equations different?

As far as I can tell, SDEs are PDEs or ODEs, where the derivative of some function wrt itself is a random variable or random process. Example, the derivative of some variable, $x$, might be the distribution, $N(0,x)$. (Fact check?)

What got me thinking about this was reading about a [PyMC3 implementation of the SIR model](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/ODE_API_introduction.html) and I wasn't sure if the model relied on (vanilla) differential equations or stochastic differential equations.

Comment: I cannot comment on the distinction between ordinary differential equations and stochastic differential equations, as I have no familiarity with the latter. What I do know is that SIR/Kermack-McKendrick is in the former category. Given initial conditions, the solutions of the system described by the three nonlinear ordinary differential equations are purely deterministic functions of time $S(t), I(t)$ and $R(t)$. That the model is non-linear just means that recourse to numerical, rather than analytical solutions are required.

Comment: From a cursory skim of the PyMC3 documentation you have cited, there are no stochastic differential equations involved, you are just doing Bayesian statistical inference on the "parameters" of the ordinary differential equations of SIR to infer a posterior.